# how to load timestamp column values to the DATE datatype column in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need to load the **timestamp** values "5/14/2013 12:00:00 AM" into the **date** column .The file I need to load is in CSV format.
I want the result should be like this "5/14/2013".I don't want the time to get loaded into the table.

Could anyone suggest the solution to resolve the issue would be very helpful

The environment am using is LINUX

Comment: There are quite a few approaches that you could take. What have you tried so far, and what didn't work? What does your CSV look like? What's the definition of the table you're loading into? Is this a one-time task or a regular job? The more details you provide the better chances for a meaningful answer you will have.

Comment: I tried in load command to modify the timestamp values to date by using "modified by date format ='m/d/yyyy',its not worked. Its a one time task. User wants to fetch the sum of amount paid per day..In timestamp its not worked out. That's why we want to change to date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "5/14/2013 12:00:00 AM" > dat.csv
echo "5/15/2013 12:01:00 AM" >> dat.csv
echo "5/16/2013 12:02:00 AM" >> dat.csv

# prepare objects for test
db2 -v "drop db db1"
db2 -v "create db db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "create table t1 (c1 date)"
db2 -v "load from dat.csv of del insert into t1"
db2 -v "select c1 from t1"
```

**Load** command returns SQL3125W, column "1" truncated warning message but 
**"select c1 from t1"** returns 3 rows as below on Db2 V11.5 + AIX.

```
C1
----------
05/14/2013
05/15/2013
05/16/2013

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Hope this helps.